# How to determine that kindle doesn't work because of the battery exactly?

Tags: kindle

My kindle is frozen. I have just a grey screen. Charging for more than 20 hours led to nothing. I tried to reset my Kindle the standard way. Then I made hard reset and even unplugged the battery. After unplugging and plugging the battery I charged kindle for a while. Still nothing.

When I connect kindle to power socket the LED light which indicates that kindle is charging turns on only for 5 seconds and then it turns off.

So, before buying a new battery, how can I ensure that the battery is the reason that my kindle does not work?

Comment: What Kindle model do you have?

Comment: I have Kindle 3 (keyboard)

Comment: This question should be sent to Amazon support.